# css transition is not working, It used to work before adding the label

Tags: css, css-transitions

This code is for the new user registration page on the online store website, but why, when pressing the "continue" button, the transition does not work

It used to work before adding the label

```css
.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.nav {
  width : 100%; 
  margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative; 
    
}

.span {
  padding: 13px 1px;
    background: url(../images/menubar.png);
    background-repeat: round;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.span::after {
  float: right;
  right: 10%;
  content: "+";
}

.slide {
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  overflow:auto;
  text-align: right;
  transition: height .4s ease;
}

.slide li {padding : 10px;}

#touchp {position: relative; opacity: 0; height: 0px;}    

#touchp:checked + .slide {height: 100%;overflow:visible} 

#touch {position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 0px;}    

#touch:checked + .slide {height: 100%;overflow:visible}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
<form action="" method="post">
<div  style="direction:ltr">
<a href="index.php">
<img class="mb-4" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="72" height="57" style="display: block;"></a></div><!--this is logo so modify it-->
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal" style="text-align:left">signup</h1>
<div class="form-floating">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX">
<label for="floatingInput">username</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
<label for="floatingInput">email</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
<label for="floatingPassword">password</label>
</div>
<div class="nav">

<label for="touchp" style="width: 100%;color: #fff;background-color: #0d6efd;border: 1px solid #0d6efd;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;border-radius: 0.375rem;">continue
</label>               
<input type="checkbox" id="touchp"> 

<ul class="slide" style="padding-left:0px !important">
<div class="form-floating">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="0123456789">
<label for="floatingInput">whatsapp number</label>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
</main>
```

this is [boosttrap.min.css](https://github.com/3bada-191/b.git)

It used to work before adding the label

i tried to adjust and use this but not wotking

```
.slide {
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: height 0.4s ease;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any button elements in your markup, nor the word 'Continue'. You're going to have to be more specific for us to be able to help.

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet we can run here in your question, and it's also linked to the CSS file you mentioned.  Please make sure this demo reproduces the issue you are having, and [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76885023/edit) if you need to make any change to it

Comment: @Daniel Black
I wrote everything in English and added the bootstrap file